# How can I align an object( text ) to a moving camera while the location of the object relative to the camera frame stays the same?

Tags: transform-orientation

I want to align a text object to a moving camera.
I need the text object to stay in the same location inside the camera frame and always face the camera frame.
I added Copy Rotation Constrain to the text. It solved the rotation aspect of the problem, but the text is moving slowly rightward. I want to fix the object in a position relative to the camera frame.
How can I fix it?
Thanks!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0IYVy71u0o

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting the camera as the parent of the text? Click text object, shift click camera, ctrl + P -> Parent Object

Comment: The solution is This simple, yet I have spent one hour more trying to find it with every fancy trick I understand! Thank you!